# UITableView background color iPad device does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

The following works in the simulator but not on the device.

This works in "ViewDidLoad":

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This does not work in "ViewDidLoad":

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.24 green:0.2 blue: 0.18 alpha:0];
```

XCODE5, Deployment Target: 6.1

I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you have `alpha` set to 0.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.24 green:0.2 blue: 0.18 alpha:0];
```

Change it to some other values other than 0.

Comment: @Unhelig BIG thank you, i have been looking at that piece of code for hours without seeing that :-)